# jQuery - On textarea change, post to php script and update div with result

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Can you guys help me out with this? I've got a form and it has a textarea where the user will paste in some text. I want to use jQuery to send the text they paste to a php script which will decode it and output some information. I've got a div, and I want that div to be updated with the html my script outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#target').change(function() {
  $.post('.php', {text: $(this).val()}, function(data){
      $('#divname').html(data);
    }
  )
}
```

This code is more right :) Script send textarea value to php($_POST['text']) and set the result text into the div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#target').change(function() {
  $('#divname').load('phplocation');
});
```

Target being your textarea id.
Divname being your divname id.
phplocation being the php file location and variables.